# Embed CiviEvent RSS Feed in CiviMail

Tags: civimail, civievent

Somebody already asked this on the old forums but there's no reply. I can see how to search for events by date then create an RSS or html version of the search results, but how do I display this in a Mailing? I'm sure it can't be that difficult but I've not managed to figure it out yet...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Would this be of help?
https://civicrm.org/extensions/fancy-tokens

" There are several tokens for different time periods of upcoming events, such as 7 days, 3 weeks, and 3 months. After inserting the token into the body of the message, you can change the numeric portion of the token to whatever you prefer. This token will produce a nicely formatted HTML list of upcoming events, ie events starting after now() but before the end of the time period chosen. All event titles will be hyperlinked to the event information page."